# Добавление класса отсутствия миниатюры в post_class() в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть такой трюк в wordpress для добавления классов к одному из дивов в посте в функции `post_class()`

```
function category_id_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    foreach((get_the_category($post->ID)) as $category)
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
        return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'category_id_class');
```

Данный код добавляет класс с названием категории. Как мне сделать, чтобы добавлялся класс в случае если нет миниатюры поста. Когда миниатюра есть функция `post_class()` добавляет класс `has_post_thumbnail`. Мне нужно чтобы добавлялся класс `no_post_thumbnail`, когда миниатюры нет. Подскажите решение пожалуйста кодом. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так должно сработать

```
function category_id_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    foreach ( get_the_category( $post->ID ) as $category ) {
        $classes[] = $category->category_nicename;
    }

    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'no_post_thumbnail';
    }

    return $classes;
}

add_filter( 'post_class', 'category_id_class' );
```

Comment: Отлично. Только код с категориями удалил за ненадобностью. Спасибо!